# What's wrong with this Prime-testing function?

Tags: haskell, primes

I've looked just about everywhere and I can't find why the following code does not work:

```
isPrime :: Int -> Bool
isPrime 1 = False
isPrime n = divTest n (floor (sqrt n))
    where
    divTest :: Int -> Int -> Bool
    divTest n test
        | test == 1         = True
        | mod n test == 0   = False
        | otherwise         = divTest n (test-1)
```

I get two errors, which are really long, so I'll put what I think are the important bits:

```
No instance for (RealFrac Int) arising from a use of ‘floor’
```

and

```
No instance for (Floating Int) arising from a use of ‘sqrt’
```

And yes, I know this probably isn't anywhere near efficient. I'm learning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sqrt` requires a float - try

```
isPrime n = divTest n (floor (sqrt (fromIntegral  n)))
```

Comment: Be careful about rounding error using floating-point numbers here. https://wiki.haskell.org/Generic_number_type#squareRoot

Answer (score 3):

Since [`sqrt`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:sqrt) is of type: `Floating a => a -> a`, you need to pass a floating point number instead of an integer. You can do this by applying [`fromIntegral`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fromIntegral) to `n`, as shown in the other answer.

Another way you could do this problem is by breaking it up into two functions.

The first function could find all factors up to `n`:

```
factors :: Integer -> [Integer]
factors n = filter divides_n [1..n]
    where divides_n m = n `mod` m == 0
```

Which works as follows:

```
*Main> factors 15
[1,3,5,15]
```

Then we could use this to check if a number is prime or not, if `factors` only contains `1` and `n`:

```
isPrime :: Integer -> Bool
isPrime n = factors n == [1,n]
```

Which works as expected:

```
*Main> isPrime 2
True
*Main> isPrime 3
True
*Main> isPrime 4
False
*Main> isPrime 5
True
*Main> isPrime 15
False
```

The benefit of this approach is that you don't have to do anything tricky to test if a number is prime or not.

Comment: For large numbers, this is quite a bit more expensive, but it will of course work.

Comment: Yeah good point. I just wanted to suggest a straightforward method for the OP.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to computing the square root is to compute the quotient *and* the remainder, and stop when the quotient is less than the divisor.

```
-- Work our way up from 3, testing odd divisors only.
divTest :: Int -> Int -> Bool
divTest n test | r == 0 = False
               | q < test = True -- test > sqrt n, and we've tested all the smaller divisors
               | otherwise = divTest n (test + 2)

isPrime :: Int -> Bool
isPrime 1 = False
isPrime 2 = True
isPrime n = n `mod` 2 /= 0 && divTest n 3
```